# The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#

I will create a folder according to the identities in the database and transfer the pictures related to that identity.  My code is like this:

```csharp
string AddImg(byte[] img, int productID, string name)
{
    string pathGet = myPath;
    string path = pathGet + productID.ToString() + "\\";

    if (img.Length > 0)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image x = (Bitmap)(new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(img));

        try
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(path, name);
            filePath = filePath.Replace("\\", @"\");

            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
            {
                byte[] info = img;
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
        
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

And the error I get is:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The file name, directory name, or volume label
> syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Users\k4mil\Projects\MyProject\PATH\5663''

I get the error in  using (`FileStream fs = File.Create(path)`) part.
What should I do?

Comment: `filePath = filePath.Replace("\\", @"\");` replaces backslash/es with backslash/es (achieves nothing). `File.Create()` creates a file in a path that must exist. Try `Directory.CreateDirectory()` to create the folder/s beforehand if they don't already exist (and `Directory.Exists()` to check).

Comment: I think it should be `FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath)` (path -> filePath)

Comment: I used directory but got error 

using (Directory dr = Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
                        {...codes...}
       }
Errors: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1674 'Directory': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo' to 'System.IO.Directory'

Comment: If FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath) then the same error will result.

Comment: Directory is a static class. Directory.CreateDirectory does returns another type... would you please stop guessing and refer to the manual befor you use functions? `using (Directory dr = Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath))` is utter nonsense. System.IO.DirectoryInfo does not implement IDisposable